# useState not updating an array at all

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to update the state of an array with React Hooks, using an input received from a child component.

This is the code for the array I'm trying to update (in my App.js file):

```
 const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const submitHandler = newResult => {
    const newArray = [...results, newResult];
    setResults(newArray);
    console.log(newArray);
    console.log(results);
  }
```

The `newArray` is updated and logged properly, with all the items that are submitted through the child component. But the state of `results` is never updated, and it always logs an empty array. It should be noted that other useState hooks in my app are working properly, only the one I'm using for this array isn't working. Does anyone know what could be wrong and how can it be fixed?

If it helps, this is the code that submits the items from the child component (Shorten.js) - these hooks are working perfectly fine:

```
    const [urlInput, setUrlInput] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const changeHandler = event => {
        setUrlInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const submitHandler = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (urlInput === "") {
            setError(true);
        }
        else {
            setError(false);

            axios.post("https://rel.ink/api/links/", {
                url: urlInput
            })
                .then(response => {
                    const newResult = {
                        original: urlInput,
                        shortened: "https://rel.ink/" + response.data.hashid
                    }

                    props.submit(newResult);
                })
                
            setUrlInput("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 6):

In your example, you cannot guarantee the `results` state has been updated at the point of your `console.log(results)`. This is because the React state update as asynchronous and applied in batches under the hood.

If you had your `console.log` call under `const [result, setResults] = useState([])` then it will get called on every render pass, and therefore you should see the updated value logged out once the `setState` function has applied your new state.

For example:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

console.log(results);

const submitHandler = newResult => {
  const newArray = [...results, newResult];
  setResults(newArray);
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

should log your new state on the next render pass.

You could also put your `console.log` in a `useEffect` which will let you know for sure that React knows your `results` have changed.

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(results);
}, [results]);

const submitHandler = newResult => {
  const newArray = [...results, newResult];
  setResults(newArray);
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

This means your `console.log(results)` will only be called when `results` changed, rather then on every render.

Comment: square bracket missing in code [results);